# Clone VBA Excel Application and Workbook object from memory

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am creating a copy of a workbook I am in by just creating a new excel application object and doing workbook.open  as shown below:

```
Sub OpenExcelInstance()

        Dim xlapp As Application
        Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlapp.Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, , True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'xlapp.Visible = True
        Set xlapp = Nothing
    
    
End Sub
```

However, our file is located on such a slow network drive I would like to figure out a faster way of opening the second instance. I have seen various examples of creating clones of VBA and VB6 objects but no examples of copying an entire application and workbook object. Is this doable with the excel application and workbook object itself to reduce having to retrieve the file from the network drive but pull from memory instead which should be faster.

Comment: Perhaps an XY problem. What is the use case for creating a copy of the workbook?

Comment: Save a copy locally and open that.  It would be useful to see the answer to BigBen's question though.  There's no way I'm aware of to "clone" the workbook except via a file.

Comment: @BigBen I have developed a lot of code in my VBA userform module but also outside of it with public variables and subroutines. I had created some code to just create a seperate instance of the userform object itself but when I click certain buttons within the userform the public subroutines and variables becomes a mess since I had not intended to make this seperate instance functionality originally and I was less strict with variable and subroutine scope in my development. However, a seperate instance of excel does not have this issue since everything is contained inside its own application

Comment: That seems like putting a Band-Aid on a gushing artery (slightly exaggerated, but really you need to avoid `Public` variables).

Comment: I agree. We are moving web based and away from excel but this is the last Band-Aid so getting this to work would be great. So there is no methodology for cloning the application object in memory and not just changing the reference?

Comment: As Tim mentioned, no, or at least none that I'm aware of.